# Can you freeze an avocado?

Tags: storage-method, freezing, avocados

Is it possible to freeze a raw unpeeled unripe avacado for use later?

If not why? If so what is the process to ensure maximum freshness?

Comment: Must be possible, most food wholesalers sell frozen avocado halves (no skin or stone). Only good for guacamole etc. as far as I can tell? Ingredients list ascorbic acid, probably to stop them going brown while processing and defrosting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Freezing affects the texture of avocados rather poorly.  Freezing a whole one or chunks will result in a mushy avocado on refreezing.  Its not recommended apparently.

[To properly freeze an avocado](http://www.avocadocentral.com/how-to/how-to-store-how-to-ripen-avocados), it should be washed, pureed (not just mashed) and frozen with a bit of lemon juice (or other applicable acid) to prevent browning.