# Can you freeze avocado in a dish?

Tags: freezing, avocados

I already know you can't [freeze an avocado](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18064/can-you-freeze-an-avocado) and have it come out usable. Is this mitigated at all, however, by the avocado being in a dish? The specific example I'm thinking of would be avocado slices or chunks in a freezer burrito. Would it be better to make guacamole? Or what if a dish has avocado cooked into it, but not pureed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule, avocado should only be frozen in [pureed form](http://www.avocadocentral.com/how-to/how-to-store-how-to-ripen-avocados). When frozen, it should be placed in an air-tight container (such as a sealable dish or freezer bag) with only enough room for expansion as it cools. The variable fat and water content of avocados is not well suited to freezing, and renders the thawed product [spongy and elastic](http://trueslant.com/mikehess/2009/06/01/frozen-avocados-suck-worse-than-youd-think/), a far cry from the normal texture of avocados.

The thawed puree, however, can be used as a sandwich spread, in the creation of dips (such as guacamole), or any recipe where solid pieces of avocado are either not desired or not required. If a dish has avocado cooked into it--again, non-solid form is preferable--the freezability of the dish would be dependent on whether or not such a dish is normally freezable (if not normally containing avocado).